# How to do the equivalent of sumif using a date that matches a date from a separate table in power bi

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I am trying to sum a row based on matching dates from 2 tables in power bi. The goal is to have both dates match from each table with the new column provided the total count of distinct records based on the date [example sumif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA04O.png)

[Failing code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vobAh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just establish a relationship between `Table1` and `Table2` on the date columns, in the relationship view. This should be a relationship with `Table2` on the one-side of the relationship, and `Table1` on the many-side. This way, `Table2` can pass filters to `Table1`.

After the relationship is established, simply add a calculated column in `Table2`:

```
Sumif = 
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table1'[Count] ) )
```

You can also add a simple measure:

```
SimpleSum = SUM ( 'Table1'[Count] )
```

And add this to a table visual together with `Table2[Date]`. This will also give you what you are after, without having to persist a calculated column to your data model. Unless you are planning to use the added column as a slicing dimension or a category, you do not need to persist it in your datamodel, and using a measure is the best practice.

Edit: Your original DAX code is throwing the error you see because you haven't closed your `FILTER` function with a parenthesis. The correct code is:

```
Col =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'acumatica wv_install_revenue_nopids',
        'acumatica vw_install_revenue_nopids'[Revenue Recognition Date] = 'Revenue Recognition Date'[Rev_Recog_Date]
    ),
    'acumatica wv_install_revenue_nopids'[Confirmed]
)
```

I suggest you start formatting your code systematically to make this easier to spot - and I would recommend avoiding ridiculously long table names like `acumatica vw_install_revenue_nopids` - makes it even harder to spot mistakes.

Comment: This was the fix! Thank you, I agree the table names are really long. We are setting up the DB and these are how the names come over from the ERP we just rolled out. I appreciate the quick reply.

Comment: Best of luck to you!